# Is there a difference in returning a function or a lambda function?

Tags: python, function, closures

Is there a difference (even subtle) between those two following codes?
(is there any special use case of second code?)

- code 1

```py
def f(n):
    def g(x):
        return x * n
    return g
```

- code 2

```py
def f(n):
    def g(x):
        return x * n
    return lambda y: g(y)
```

Comment: The `g` function carries its `__name__` (not necessarily the variable name), a lambda doesn't. The tracebacks would be slightly different and the second variant is slightly less efficient because of the additional function call.

Comment: There are some small differences in the `__code__` attribute of the returned value, which defines the properties of a function, and as michael has mentioned, `__name__` is only relevant for non-lambda functions.

Comment: "is there any special use case of second code?" no. It's a convoluted way of just saying `g` if `g` ends up having the same signature anyway. It is pointless, and in any code review, I would make people change it to just `g`

Comment: A better question would be if code 3 (`def f(n): return lambda x: x * n`) is different from code 1. The answer would be "not significantly so" (ignoring the subtle differences mentioned by others regarding `__name__` and `__code__` attributes of the return value.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we use `dis`, Python's builtin CodeObject disassembler module, many differences are apparent in the functions. This will be different in 3.11, but I have not updated from 3.10.

For the first function

```
  2           0 LOAD_CLOSURE             0 (n)
              2 BUILD_TUPLE              1
              4 LOAD_CONST               1 (<code object g at 0x000001F59E179000, file "<pyshell#2>", line 2>)
              6 LOAD_CONST               2 ('f.<locals>.g')
              8 MAKE_FUNCTION            8 (closure)
             10 STORE_FAST               1 (g)

  4          12 LOAD_FAST                1 (g)
             14 RETURN_VALUE

Disassembly of <code object g at 0x000001F59E179000, file "<pyshell#2>", line 2>:
  3           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              2 LOAD_DEREF               0 (n)
              4 BINARY_MULTIPLY
              6 RETURN_VALUE
```

And for the second:

```
  2           0 LOAD_CLOSURE             1 (n)
              2 BUILD_TUPLE              1
              4 LOAD_CONST               1 (<code object g at 0x000001F59E1A52C0, file "<pyshell#5>", line 2>)
              6 LOAD_CONST               2 ('f.<locals>.g')
              8 MAKE_FUNCTION            8 (closure)
             10 STORE_DEREF              0 (g)

  4          12 LOAD_CLOSURE             0 (g)
             14 BUILD_TUPLE              1
             16 LOAD_CONST               3 (<code object <lambda> at 0x000001F59E1A5420, file "<pyshell#5>", line 4>)
             18 LOAD_CONST               4 ('f.<locals>.<lambda>')
             20 MAKE_FUNCTION            8 (closure)
             22 RETURN_VALUE

Disassembly of <code object g at 0x000001F59E1A52C0, file "<pyshell#5>", line 2>:
  3           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              2 LOAD_DEREF               0 (n)
              4 BINARY_MULTIPLY
              6 RETURN_VALUE

Disassembly of <code object <lambda> at 0x000001F59E1A5420, file "<pyshell#5>", line 4>:
  4           0 LOAD_DEREF               0 (g)
              2 LOAD_FAST                0 (y)
              4 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              6 RETURN_VALUE
```

The attributes of the `__code__` attribute on each function that are different are

- `co_cellvars` - `'n'` is also present in the second function
- `co_code` - the second function builds a lambda before returning; the first function returns `g` directly
- `co_consts` - the second function contains two CodeObjects (and two corresponding names), whereas the first only contains one CodeObject with its name
- `co_lines` - The `co_lines` method will return different values when iterated over as a direct consequence of `co_code` being different
- `co_lnotab` - The (deprecated in 3.11) `co_lnotab` attribute is a more space-efficient version of the `co_lines` method
- `co_nlocals` - I'm not sure why this differs
- `co_varnames` - `g` is present in the first function, because it's directly referenced in the first function. However in the second function it's only referenced within the lambda scope, and so occurs in `f.__code__.co_consts[3].co_freevars`, the free variables of the lambda instead.

Finally, as Michael notes in the comments, the `__name__` of all lambda functions, such as those returned here, is `'<lambda>'`.